# Change Excel Range Background Color

Tags: c#, excel

i try to Change with C# the Background Color of a specific Range in an Excel Worksheet.

My Code:

```
    this.worksheetResult.Select();
    this.worksheetResult.Cells[1,1].Value = "Export1";
    this.worksheetResult.Range["A1:G1"].Merge();
    var Section1 = this.worksheetResult.Range["A1:G1"];
    Section1.Interior.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
```

Eyerything I tried wont work. either a HResult error shows up, or this Error Message:`"Value does not Fall within the expected range."`

Could need some quick help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved already the Problem. I used the System.Drawing Library but in

```
Section1.Interior.Color = Colors.LightBlue;
```

"Colors" there was used another Library that shouldn´t. So i just addes the correct Library before Colors.

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using to accomplish this? And have you tried to debug to get the exact line where the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

using System.Drawing;
.
.
.
Section1.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightBlue);